# JavaScript MongoDB query comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, undefined

I have the following query in my server.js file:

```
Breed.find({$and: [
    {$or: [ { size: 's' }, { size: 'm' } ]},
    {$or: [ { exercise: 'two' }, { exercise: 'three' } ]},
    {$or: [ { training: 'two' }, { training: 'three' } ]},
    {$or: [ { grooming: 'two' }, { grooming: 'three' } ]},
    {$or: [ { catfriendly: 'two' }, { catfriendly: 'three' } ]},
    {$or: [ { protective: 'two' }, { protective: 'three' } ]},
    {$or: [ { affection: 'three' }, { affection: 'four' } ]}
    ]}, function (err, matches) {
    console.log('these are the matches: ' + matches);
    res.json(matches);
});
```

It comes back as undefined.  But I've run this query in the Mongo terminal:

```
db.breeds.find({$and: [ {$or: [ { size: 's' }, { size: 'm' } ]},{$or: [ { exercise: 'two' }, { exercise: 'three' } ]}, {$or: [ { training: 'two' }, { training: 'three' } ]},{$or: [ { grooming: 'two' }, { grooming: 'three' } ]},{$or: [ { catfriendly: 'two' }, { catfriendly: 'three' } ]},{$or: [ { protective: 'two' }, { protective: 'three' } ]},{$or: [ { affection: 'three' }, { affection: 'four' } ]}]});
```

And it returns 4 breeds that match the query.  What am I missing in my server.js file that is making it come back undefined?  I tried console logging typeof matches and it said undefined as well.

Comment: are you requiring the model in your server.js file?

Comment: Just for notes, the whole query is much more clearly written using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and also without the `$and` as all MongoDB query arguments are implicitly an "and" condition anyway. If you are still unsure then provide the document(s) you expect to match in your question. It also looks like you are using `mongoose`, so be sure your schema definitions match the types required ( all should be string ).

Comment: I will definitely look into $in, thanks!  Using $and is necessary when you use the $or operator more than once per the mongodb docs https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: Yes, I have this at the top:
 Breed = require('./models/breed');

Comment: My point is when you use `$in` it replaces the `$or` in  way that `$and` is not necessary. Show the document(s) you think you will match so we can compare ourselves.

Comment: @pro you saved the day.  I forgot to update my breed.js file after I changed the characteristics values from numbers to strings, so the model was still expecting numbers to come through.  Thank you!  If you want to write an official answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: are you referring to my answer or Blake's lol

Comment: @BlakesSeven here's one of the documents that would match: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("562567485590dbec0c40072a"), "size" : "s", "catfriendly" : "three", "training" : "three", "watchdog" : "six", "grooming" : "two", "coldtolerant" : "four", "breed" : "Dachshund (Standard)", "energy" : "five", "playfulness" : "four", "dogfriendly" : "four", "strangerfriendly" : "two", "protective" : "three", "heattolerant" : "four", "exercise" : "three", "affection" : "four" }` and I think you're right about `$in`, I'm reading the docs on it now and it seems much more simple.

Comment: @pro Your answer.  Yours lead me to what was actually going wrong.  Blakes' is leading me to a cleaner way to write my code, but wouldn't have fixed this particular issue.

Comment: alright..you can accept it now.

Comment: Actually I did say excatly to check your schema that all types were in fact `String`. The form of `$in` basically starts like this: `{ "size": { "$in": [ "s", "m" ] }, "excercise": { "$in": [ "two", "three" ] } }` and so on where each field is an implicit "and" and the `$in` is effectively a shortened `$or`.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Oh, yeah, you did.  Well, I'll leave pro as the solution since he posted a minute before you and still led me to the fix.  A huge thank you though for pointing me to `$in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your requiring your Breed model in server.js?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to check on the breed model!  I had updated the value type in the database from number to string, but not in the breed.js file.